question about ipywidgets and running a different process
what is a better way to run this launching function separately from the ipywidgets process?
from IPython.display import display
from multiprocessing import Process
from ipywidgets import widgets
from pathlib import Path
import time

main_widget = widgets.VBox([top, middle, launch_button])
text = Path('launch.txt')

def if_launch(b):
    main_widget.close()
    Path('launch.txt').write_text('ready to launch')

def something():
    while not text.exists():
        time.sleep(2)

    launching()

def widget():
    display(main_widget)

    launch_button.on_click(if_launch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        widget()

        p = Process(target=something)
        p.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

This works as I expected, even if I clear the output using the context menu in Jupyter Notebook, the Process continues and prints its output in the notebook cell, it's just losing the [*] cell mark.
I'm just curious if there is a better way instead of using a while loop.

Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is perfectly OK, I don't think there needs to be much improvement.

thanks, I found about multiprocessing.Condition

There's also this if you want to explore refactoring to use asyncio.

@Wayne that turned out better thank you.

Sorry, I didn't have my full notes earlier. You may also wish to look into here, here, here, and here.

since I can't get the asyncio code right, it losing the IPython ability to clear output and display images on my test.
I'll post the answer with what I think I get what I want.
from IPython.display import display
from multiprocessing import Process, Condition, Value
from ipywidgets import widgets

main_widget = widgets.VBox([top, middle, launch_button])

condition = Condition()
ready = Value('b', False)

def if_launch(b):
    main_widget.close()

    with condition:
        ready.value = True
        condition.notify()

def something(condition, ready):
    with condition:
        while not ready.value:
            condition.wait()

    launching()

def widget():
    display(main_widget)

    launch_button.on_click(if_launch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        widget()

        p = Process(target=something, args=(condition, ready))
        p.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

